# Command to list in real time all the actions of a process

Tags: process, files, real-time

I cannot remember this command (and googling was unsuccessful), but there is a way to get the list of actions performed by a process, that outputs something like

```
  # listprocessactions -p 1234
  0.321 Open "A" /var/log/nginx/supersite.log
  0.322 Write to /var/log/nginx/supersite.log
  0.401 Close /var/log/nginx/supersite.log
  0.555 Opens TCP connection with slashdot.org
  ...
```

I'm interested in the files aspect (open / RW files).
The question is what is that command (and if possible in which package on deb / ubuntu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want [strace(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) for that; it lists all the system calls made.  See the manual page for details on various ways to present the trace data.

You might also find [ltrace(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace) useful if you want inter-library calls rather than system calls traced.