# Record time of every process or thread context switch

Tags: process, logs, debugging, real-time, profiling

I'm trying to get the nearest to real-time processing I can with a Raspbian distribution on a Raspberry Pi for manipulating its GPIO pins. I want to get a "feel" for the kind of performance I can expect.

I was going to do this by writing a simple C program that toggles a pin repeatedly as fast as possible, and monitoring it with a logic analyser.

But perhaps there's another way, by writing the above program but simply logging context switches to see exactly when that thread/process has control over a sample period of say a couple of seconds.

[This previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39342/how-to-see-how-many-context-switches-a-process-makes) answers how to see how many context switches are made in some period of time for a given process, but is there a way of logging the precise timing of switches, and perhaps for every process, not just one? Obviously this would create overhead, but could still be useful. Obviously the data should be stored in RAM to minimise overhead

Note to self: possible solutions:

- [Command to list in real time all the actions of a process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33435/command-to-list-in-real-time-all-the-actions-of-a-process?rq=1)
- Hacky: make the program repeatedly get and store the current time (and save it to a file once the log reaches a certain limit). Or, a slight improvement to avoid enormous logs: use an algorithm that eliminates consecutive times if they are close enough together that it can be deduced they were not pre-empted by some other process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an answer but you might find one amongst the [tools, examples and resources](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html) written or listed by 
Brendan Gregg on the `perf` command and Linux kernel ftrace and debugfs.

On my Raspberry Pi these tools were in package `perf-tools-unstable`. The `perf` command was actually in `/usr/bin/perf_3.16`.

---

Of interest may be this [discussion](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/11/how-long-does-it-take-to-make-context.html) and context-switch [benchmark](https://github.com/tsuna/contextswitch) by Benoit Sigoure, and the [lat_ctx](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/lat_ctx.8.html) test from the fairly old [lmbench](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lmbench/) suite.

They may need some work to run on the Pi, for example with `tsuna/contextswitch` I edited `timectxswws.c` `get_iterations()` to `while (iterations * ws_pages * 4096UL < 4294967295UL) {`, and removed `-march=native -mno-avx` from the `Makefile`.

---

Using `perf record` for 10 seconds on the Pi over ssh whilst simultaneously doing `while sleep .1;do echo hi;done` in another ssh:

```
sudo timeout -10 perf_3.16 record -e context-switches -a
sudo perf_3.16 script -f time,pid,comm | less
```

gives output like this

```
           sleep 29341 2703976.560357: 
         swapper     0 2703976.562160: 
    kworker/u8:2 29163 2703976.564901: 
         swapper     0 2703976.565737: 
            echo 29342 2703976.565768: 
     migration/3    19 2703976.567549: 
           sleep 29343 2703976.570212: 
     kworker/0:0 28906 2703976.588613: 
     rcu_preempt     7 2703976.609261: 
           sleep 29343 2703976.670674: 
            bash 29066 2703976.671654: 
            echo 29344 2703976.675065: 
            sshd 29065 2703976.675454: 
         swapper     0 2703976.677757:
```

presumably showing when a context-switch event happened, for which process.

Comment: I  added links to some context-switch benchmark code.

Comment: I'm finding it really difficult to know what to do, my skills on Linux are really weak - I really appreciate the help you've given, but  I've spent a while trying to understand how to use what you've given, and I think this is just over my head! Am I right in saying that tsuna/contextswitch measures context switching times themselves, rather than how long processes are active for?

Comment: Yes, the benchmarks try to measure one single thing, so you can compare one platform to another. But I think you are right, you should go back to your original idea: there are so many variables in a final real-world implementation that there is nothing better than getting as close as you can to simulating it with dummy cpu loads, dummy network traffic, and real gpio interrupts and so on. If you just want to *bit bang* data to an SPI device or similar, I'm sure you can find people who have found the max throughput for the Pi.

Comment: I added a possible `perf` example, but I'm no expert on this.